# i want to get data from api with bearer token flutter, no error, but data not showing

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I want to get data jobs from API with bearer token flutter, no error, but data not showing.

I don't understand getting API with the bearer token.

please help me.

thanks..

**jobs_service.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:nyoba/models/jobs_model.dart';
import 'package:nyoba/models/user_model.dart';

class JobsServices {
  String baseUrl = 'https://link-id.com/api';
  var token = UserModel().token;

  Future<List<JobsModel>> getJobs() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/vacancy');
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': '$token',
    };
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

    print(response.body);
    print(token);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['data'];
      List<JobsModel> jobs = [];
      for(var item in data){
        jobs.add(JobsModel.fromJson(item));
      }
      return jobs;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get jobs');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `var token` have 'Bearer' in it already? You might have to include it like this:

```dart
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
}
```

Though normally you'd get a 401 forbidden back, and not a 200 if you made the request with an invalid token

Comment: thank you for answering,
but still not working

Comment: But you do get an HTTP response? You can check out what the HTTP status code is, what the data therein is. You might be able to access the API documentation to figure out if you're missing something in your API call or while parsing the response

Comment: I see that when you use `HttpHeaders.authorization`, it uses the value `authorization` (lower case) whereas you've used capital letters. The same goes for `content-type`. I'm not sure if this matters, but you can try making both of these lower case as well.

Answer (score 0):

**user_model.dart**

```
class UserModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? profilePhotoUrl;
  String? token;

  UserModel ({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.profilePhotoUrl,
    this.token,
  });

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    email = json['email'];
    password = json['password'];
    profilePhotoUrl = json['photo'];
    token = json['token'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'photo': profilePhotoUrl,
      'token': token,
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).